# What is the "Control.Site" Property?

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

In Windows Forms applications, controls in the `System.Windows.Forms` library have a property named [`Site`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24sf20kb(v=vs.110).aspx).
What is this property’s job in Controls?

Comment: I don't see that Property. Have you added something to your form that adds it in? (Like a ToolTip component adds in the Tooltips properites?)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.site%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: See the remarks section on [ISite Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isite.aspx) documentation. Basicly, a site is what links a `Component` and a `Container`

Comment: It is purely a design-time property and does not get used at all at runtime.  It is the basic reason why you can drop a component on a form and get it to appear in the bar underneath the design view of the form,, the Site will reference the form object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Site` property is inherited from `Component`, and is very much like the `Parent` property of a `Control`.

The main difference between `Parent` and `Site` is that the value of `Parent` can only be a `Control`, while `Site` can have a non-visual container assigned to it.

The `Component` base-class is used for those non-visual tools in the Winforms designer toolbox. For example the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` which can be dragged onto a `Form`. The PropertyGrid can be used to set its properties and assign event-handlers, all from the designer without writing a line of code.

The idea behind the `System.ComponentModel` classes is to provide an API for Software libraries to take advantage of design-time capabilities of an IDE such as Visual Studio. It caters to [RAD (Rapid Application Development)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rapid_application_development) concepts where general-purpose or generic components would take advantage of the API. For example to [expose extra information about a property](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1) in the bottom section of the property-grid, or even create complete [custom editors](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.design.componentdesigner).

If you want to dive deeper into the internals you could look at [Programming with Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ffkdtkf.aspx), or if you want a quick overview, I guess [Class vs. Component vs. Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1dk63b.aspx) may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Sites bind a [Component](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.component.aspx) to a [Container](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.container.aspx) and enable communication between them, as well as provide a way for the container to manage its components.
Sites can also serve as a repository for container-specific, per-component information, such as the component name. For more information about components, see [Programming with Components](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ffkdtkf.aspx).

> **Notes to Implementers**
>
> To be a site, a class must implement the ISite interface.

Reference:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isite.aspx